# jQuery - Switch Between Classes Every Click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm working on a sidebar that pops in out and from the left of the page. The element that toggles the sidebar is the navbar-brand button on a Bootstrap navbar. I have an`<i>` inside of the `<a>` tag to act as an icon and have these two surrounded by a `<div>` to be the click area. It looks like this:

```
<div id = "sheath-toggle" class = "sheath-toggle-icon">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href = "#"><i class = "glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></i></a>
</div>
```

When the sidebar is not displayed, the icon is a hamburger icon. When the sidebar pops out, the icon changes to a left arrow, and back to a hamburger when you close it.

Originally, this is the jQuery I was using to change the icon.

```
$(".sheath-toggle-icon").click(function() {
    if ( $(this).find("i").hasClass("glyphicon-menu-hamburger") ) {
        $("i").switchClass("glyphicon-menu-hamburger", "glyphicon-menu-left");
    } else if ( $(this).find("i").hasClass("glyphicon-menu-left") ) {
        $("i").switchClass("glyphicon-menu-left", "glyphicon-menu-hamburger");
    }
})
```

This was working fine for me until I decided I wanted another `<i>`elsewhere on the page for another icon. What I discovered is that my script was also changing the class on this icon, when it should only be switching the icon on my toggle element. How can I re-write this script to only affect the classes on my toggling element and not the other `<i>` icons on my page? Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: check `toggleClass` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("i") selects all the icons on your page.
```

You need to rewrite your code like this -

```
$(".sheath-toggle-icon").click(function() {
    var icon = $(this).find("i");
    if (icon.hasClass("glyphicon-menu-hamburger") ) {
        icon.switchClass("glyphicon-menu-hamburger", "glyphicon-menu-left");
    } else if ( icon.hasClass("glyphicon-menu-left") ) {
        icon.switchClass("glyphicon-menu-left", "glyphicon-menu-hamburger");
    }
})
```

Comment: Trying this now. I just thought that .find() looked for only descending children so I'm confused why it's finding all "i"s EDIT: This worked liked a charm. It isn't even that different from what I had so I don't get it. But thank you very much!

Comment: My code should have worked based on the fact that I was looking for "i"s that had the specific class. Why would it find the others without that class?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Tushar Arora for this corrected script

```
$(".sheath-toggle-icon").click(function() {
    var icon = $(this).find("i");
    if (icon.hasClass("glyphicon-menu-hamburger") ) {
        icon.switchClass("glyphicon-menu-hamburger", "glyphicon-menu-left");
    } else if ( icon.hasClass("glyphicon-menu-left") ) {
        icon.switchClass("glyphicon-menu-left", "glyphicon-menu-hamburger");
    }
})
```